# 'Required argument not found' error when calling cv2.putText()

Tags: python, opencv, dlib

In this line I am getting the following error:

```py
cv2.putText(image,"Unknown" + str(conf), (J.left(), J.bottom()),font, 200)
```

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\PROJECT ALL RESOURCE\PROJECT ALL RESOURCE\Implementation\PYTHON FILES\facerecognition.py", line 73, in <module>
    (J.left(), J.bottom()),font, 200)                                            # Writing the name of the face recognized
TypeError: Required argument 'color' (pos 6) not found
```

Can you describe to me what this error message is about?

Comment: you might want to go through some basic python function-related tutorials before you get further in that code.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear, is it not? It says that argument 'color' is not found, and was expected in position 6 of your function call. Did you check the documentation for this function?

Answer (score 2):

See https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-opencv-cv2-puttext-method/.
cv2.putText() requires image, text, org, font, fontScale and the sixth parameter color.
You are calling it with five paramenters only.